# Вывести список в 4 колонки и равномерно распределить контент по колонкам

Tags: css, списки

Вывести список с одинаковым заполнением в колонке.
Почему в последней (4) колонке только один `li`?
Нужно чтобы равномерно распределялся контент по всем колонкам.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
    column-fill: balance;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/2353/

Comment: Давайте немного забудем про css и логически подумаем как равномерно разделить 10 на 4

Comment: Потому что заполнение идет не по горизонтали, а по вертикали. Замените 1..1 на 1,2,3...10 и уведите.

Answer (score 2):

С использованием `li`, незабываем убирать пустые текстовые узлы:

```css
   ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: вот заполнение нужно такое же, а порядок по вертикали (в первой колонке 1, 2, 3; во второй 4, 5, 6, в третьей 7, 8; в четвертой 9, 10) и одним потоком (один ul)